# Goland Search functionality not indexing all files in project

Tags: goland

I'm using Goland version 2021.1 on a mac, and recently I've noticed when searching for files, symbols, or types (using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>), it doesn't index across my entire project. For example, if I have two files `A.txt` in two different directories, the file search will only show one of them.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue, please see [IDEA-266391](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266391). You can download [Toolbox App](http://toolbox.app/) and install the Nightly build of GoLand.

As another workaround, you can invalidate caches via `File | Invalidate Caches`.